# Use the dynamic value from selectinput in R leaflet setview

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet, shiny

I'm creating a shiny leaflet map to record where I have been. I have a dataset contains coordinates and time. In my shiny app I've got 2 widgets-- a sliderbard for time line, a dropdown box to show the current countries that I have been. The country choices in the dropdown box is based on the time line sliderbar. Say for example: before 2016 all coordinates on the map are in country A then in the dropdown box there will be only one option in the dropdown box (country A). After 2016-01-01, the number of countries that I have been increased to 2 then in the dropdown box there will be 2 options (country A and country B) and currently this function works well.

Now I want to further develop my shiny app, the function I want is when I have multiple countries in the dropdown box, the app should allow me to choose one of the countries and when the country is chosen, the leaflet map will focus on the country I choose. I think using if else in `setview()` should solve the problem.

Then I created a (partially) workable shiny script below:

```
global.R
df <-read.csv("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5w09dayyeav7hzy/Coordinatestest.csv",
           header = T,
           stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Time <- as.Date(df$Time, "%m/%d/%Y")
countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='low')
```

and

```
ui.R
library(devtools)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sp)
library(rworldmap)
library(RCurl)

header <- dashboardHeader(
   title = 'Shiny Memery'
)
body <- dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
  tabBox(
  tabPanel("My Map", leafletOutput("mymap",height = 550)),
  width = 700
))

)


dashboardPage(
header,
dashboardSidebar(

sliderInput('Timeline Value','Time line',min = min(df$Time),max =    max(df$Time), value = min(df$Time)),

selectInput("select_country", label = "Select Country", 
            choices = NULL, 
            selected = NULL)

),
body
)
```

and

```
server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {



output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

df <- subset(df, df$Time <= input$`Timeline Value`)

observe({

  pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(df[,c("lon", "lat")],  proj4string=CRS(proj4string(countriesSP)))

  indices <- over(pointsSP, countriesSP)

  part_choices <- as.list(c("All",  na.omit(unique(as.character(indices$ADMIN)))))

  updateSelectInput(session, "select_country", choices=part_choices)
})

  lng <- ifelse(input$select_country == "All", mean(df$lon), 0)
  lat <- ifelse(input$select_country == "All", mean(df$lat), 0)


  m <- leaflet(df) %>%
    addTiles(
    #urlTemplate = "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ) %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  #setView(mean(df$lon), mean(df$lat), zoom = 5) %>%
  setView(lng, lat, zoom = 5) %>%
  addMarkers(~lon, ~lat, 
             clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

 })

})
```

Please copy and paste the script into Rstudio and run it. You will see as you drag the time line till the end, the country option will increase but default is always **All**. Ideally when I select one country and as you see based on some simple logic as long as the selection is not **All**, the coordinates in `setview()` function should be (0,0) (this can be dynamic later, currently I just want `setview()` to change the focus of the map). This function is not really working currently, i.e. when I select other country, the focus of the map will change to (0,0) but again change back to the default focus (`mean(df$lon)`, `mean(df$lat)`) immediately and the selection will change back to **All** as well.

So any idea on how to alter my code to make this work?

Hope you are clear about my situation in this example.

Much appreciate for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the server.R part how I think this should be done. Let me know if this helps.

server.R

```
     shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

            dfs <- reactive({
                    tmp <- subset(df, df$Time <= input$`Timeline Value`)  
                    tmp
            })

            part_choices <- reactive({
                    tmp <- dfs()
                    pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(tmp[,c("lon", "lat")],  proj4string=CRS(proj4string(countriesSP)))
                    indices <- over(pointsSP, countriesSP)
                    as.list(c("All",  na.omit(unique(as.character(indices$ADMIN)))))
            })

            observe({
                    updateSelectInput(session, "select_country", choices=part_choices())
            })
             output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                     lng <- ifelse(input$select_country == "All", mean(df$lon), 0)
                     lat <- ifelse(input$select_country == "All", mean(df$lat), 0)
                     m <- leaflet(dfs()) %>%
                             addTiles(
                                     #urlTemplate = "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                             ) %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
                             #setView(mean(dfs()$lon), mean(dfs()$lat), zoom = 5) %>%
                             setView(lng, lat, zoom = 5) %>%
                             addMarkers(~lon, ~lat, 
                                        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

            })

    })
```

Comment: Hi @Valter thanks for the help. It's working really well. May I ask why things are going to work in this way? It seems that you move some parts outside `renderLeaflet` and give them `reactive` function. What is the rules it's based on and what should I pay attention when it comes to the similar situation? Thanks

Comment: If you have time I suggest to watch the two videos for the Shiny Developer Conference about reactive programming by @joecheng. It cleared many points for me. [This is the link](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/)